# Storing text files > 1MB in GAE/P

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-docs-api, blobstore, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google App Engine app where I need to store text files that are larger than 1 MB (the maximum entity size.

I'm currently storing them in the Blobstore and I make use of the Files API for reading and writing them.  Current operations including uploading them from a user, reading them to process and update, and presenting them to a user.  Eventually, I would like to allow a user to edit them (likely as a Google doc).

Are there advantages to storing such text files in Google Cloud Storage, as a Google Doc, or in some other location instead of using the Blobstore?

Comment: You mean other advantages apart from the ones you already mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what exactly you need. There are of course advantages of using [one service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs) over the [other](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/pricingandterms#pricing), but in the end it really doesn't matter, since all of the solutions will be almost equally fast and not that expensive. If you will have a huge amount of data after some time you might consider switching to another solution, just because you might save some money.

Having said that, I will suggest you to continue with the [Blobstore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/), since that will not require extra communication with external services, more secret keys, etc. Security and speed wise it is exactly the same. When you will reach 10K or 100K users you will already going to know if it'actually worth it to store them somewhere else. Continue with what you know best, but just make sure that you're following the right practices when building on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using the Files API to read and write the files, I'd recommend you use Google Cloud Storage rather than the Blobstore. GCS offers a richer RESTful API (makes it easier to do things like access control), does a number of things to accelerate serving static data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing data is more easy in Google Docs (now Google Drive) and Google Cloud Storage. Using Google drive u can also use the power of Google Apps scripts.